# How to find label value inside repeater control using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to find label value inside repeater control using C#?

The aspx and C# code shown below, but I am not getting the output.

**aspx Content**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Batch</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrBatch">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:Label ID="lbBatchID" runat="server"><%#Eval("id")%></asp:Label>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lbBatchName" runat="server"><%#Eval("Name")%></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:CheckBox id="cbBatch" runat="server"/></td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrLevel">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:Label ID="lbLevelID" runat="server"><%#Eval("id")%></asp:Label>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lbLevelName" runat="server"><%#Eval("Name")%></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:CheckBox id="cbLevel" runat="server" CssClass="cbLevel"/></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
    </table>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSave" OnClick="lnkSave_Click" >Save</asp:LinkButton>
```

**C# Code**

```
 protected void lnkSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        GetCheckBoxValue(rptrBatch, "cbBatch", "lbBatchID", "lbBatchName");
        GetCheckBoxValue(rptrLevel, "cbLevel", "lbLevelID", "lbLevelName");
      }


           private void GetCheckBoxValue(Repeater RptrName, string CheckboxName, string labelID, string labelName)
           {
                    Label CellId,CellValue;
                    string cellId, cellValue;
                    CheckBox chk;
                    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in RptrName.Items)
                        {
                            chk = (CheckBox)ri.FindControl(CheckboxName);
                            if (chk.Checked)
                                {
                                CellId = (Label)ri.FindControl(labelID);
                                cellId = CellId.Text.ToString();
                                CellValue =      (Label)ri.FindControl(labelName);
                                cellValue = CellValue.Text.ToString();
                                  }
                         }
                }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean `Not getting output` ? What error do you face ?

Comment: It's showing null value in **cellId** and **cellValue**

Comment: Where are you binding the Reapter if it is in page load please check if the `IsPostback` is checked or not before binding? Does `Label` control found  on `fincontrol` method ??

Comment: if (chk.Checked)
                                {
                                **CellId = (Label)ri.FindControl(labelID);**

Comment: Here is page load details
  **protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   if (!IsPostBack)
    {
     LoadBatch();
     LoadLevel();
    }
   }
  private void LoadBatch()
  {
   rptrBatch.DataSource = DBContext.Batch_Select();
   rptrBatch.DataBind();
  }
  private void LoadBatch()
  {
   rptrBatch.DataSource = DBContext.Level_Select();
   rptrBatch.DataBind();
  }**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `Labels` `Text` property in the aspx page.

```
<asp:Label ID="lbBatchID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id")%>'></asp:Label>
<td><asp:Label ID="lbBatchName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label></td>
```